# Generate a flag if table has more than one duplicate row using group by in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql table

```
ID     ref
1      AOO
2      BGH
3      AOO
```

My query is

```
$getdup = "select * from coderef group by ref"
```

Now I get

```
ID   ref
1    AOO
2    BGH
```

Is it possible to create another column beside ref for eg 'notes' saying 'View more' if there are more than 1 item

```
ID   ref   notes
1    AOO   view more
2    BGH
```

Any help  is highly appreciated.

Comment: `select * from coderef group by ref` is not valid SQL. Only the columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause can appear in the `SELECT` clause unless they are used as arguments of [aggregate (`GROUP BY`) functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: This is a sample sql and not the final one. I wanted to know the use of case/if expression.

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that the query `select * from coderef group by ref` is rejected by MySQL 5.7.5 and newer and [may return either `(1, 'AOO')` or `(3, 'AOO')` on different runs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) on older versions. Other RDBMSes just reject it as being invalid SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression which checks the count of each reference code, and displays `'view more'` should there be more than one code.  Note that I omitted the `ID` from the query, because it isn't clear *which* `ID` you want to show.

```
SELECT
    ref,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'view more' END AS notes
    -- MIN(ID) AS ID       you could include this
FROM coderef
GROUP BY ref
```

Comment: Many thanks Tim. 'CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'view more' END AS notes' worked great.